# how to get RGB888 (24 - bit) and RGB565 (16-bit) framebuffer dump from a jpg image?

Tags: c, image-processing

I need to resize ( either upscale or downscale) my image in jpg/png format. I'm using Bilinear interpolation to resize. My code works fine with values I gave in an array. But to test the result with an image, I need RGB565 and RGB888 dump.

As my task is to just resize the image, I would appreciate if I can get a dump with width and height of the image or just an algorithm would also do.

I am working on C. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I correctly understand your question. But it seems that your looking for a library to decode PNG and JPEG images. Well have a look at [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net) and [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: @Codo ok thanks. But I need to decode them to RGB565 format.. how can I do that? And If I already have libjpeg library installed in my linux system, will this libjpeg source code be still useful??

Answer (score 2):

If all you're missing is a conversion from RGB888 to RGB565, then it's easy. Call this following function for each pixel:

```
unsigned short int rgb888Torgb565(unsigned int rgb888Pixel)
{
    int red   = (rgb888Pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (rgb888Pixel >> 8 ) & 0xff;
    int blue  =  rgb888Pixel        & 0xff;

    unsigned short  b =   (blue  >> 3) & 0x001f;
    unsigned short  g = ( (green >> 2) & 0x003f ) << 5;
    unsigned short  r = ( (red   >> 3) & 0x001f ) << 11;

    return (unsigned short int) (r | g | b);
}
```

Apply the function to all pixels. Each one will shrink from 3 bytes to 2 bytes.

Comment: Thanks alot.. But my problem is that I don't have the image in converted form, be it rgb888. I just have an image and i have to apply  my algorithm to resize it. That is why I need to convert jpg file to rgb888 or rgb565. Please tell me if somehow I can convert image into RGB888 format.

Comment: Yes, libjpeg and libpng can convert the image to RGB888. RGB888 is a simple format where the red, green and blue component of each pixel uses 1 byte (8 bit). In libpng, RGB888 is the format PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB with a bit depth 8. But it isn't a single function you can call. You will need to study the documentation of libpng.

Comment: The green part need to place at 5th bit, `unsigned short  g = ( (green >> 2) & 0x003f ) << 5;`

Answer (score 1):

My solution to convert a png to raw RGB 565 format in Python (called png2fb.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PIL import Image

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    # print "\nReading: " + sys.argv[1]
    out = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    out = sys.stdout
else:
    print "Usage: png2fb.py infile [outfile]"
    sys.exit(1)

im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])

if im.mode == "RGB":
    pixelSize = 3
elif im.mode == "RGBA":
    pixelSize = 4
else:
    sys.exit('not supported pixel mode: "%s"' % (im.mode))

pixels = im.tostring()
pixels2 = ""
for i in range(0, len(pixels) - 1, pixelSize):
    pixels2 += chr(ord(pixels[i + 2]) >> 3 | (ord(pixels[i + 1]) << 3 & 0xe0))
    pixels2 += chr(ord(pixels[i]) & 0xf8 | (ord(pixels[i + 1]) >> 5 & 0x07))
out.write(pixels2)
out.close()
```

Comment: Works great after fixing that import. There should be a `from PIL import Image` instead of `Image`.